# Floating Panel (overlapping with align)

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it somehow possible to float (overlapping with align) children in a panel in wpf.
I have 4 Buttons that overlap each other. They need to align to the left, right, top and bottom and grow with the parent container. Please take a look on the image for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Left"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Right"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Top"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

which results in

[image]